# homemade glyph in lualatex

Tags: characters

Is possible to join/glue 2 or more glyph and change orginal font?

For example I need 'a'='a' and 'dot' above or under 
or k=f+k but f is small and up than small k.

And change orginal a and k?
here example:
[image]

Comment: (Lua/Xe/pdf)(La)TeX are not font design programs, you may want to look at programs like [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/).

Comment: I'm not ask a NEW font but glue 2 or more glyph. ugly example: ą=a+cedila I need some letter to change normal letter s = s+ small o inside s etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve your goals using TeX's "primitive" commands `\kern`, `\lower`, and `\hbox`. These commands work the same way under luatex and pdftex.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath}
\newcommand\normalk{\text{\sffamily k}}
\newcommand\kf{\text{\sffamily k\kern-0.3em\lower-0.7ex\hbox{\tiny f}}}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
$\normalk=\kf$
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, but what i can convert my \kf command into normal k letter?

Comment: @Pankracy - Please see the edited version of my answer for both a "normal k" and a k with a small f on top.

Comment: The kerning is wrong: `\normalk x = \kf x`. Maybe: `\ooalign{\hss\kern.05em\lower.7ex\hbox{\tiny f}\hss\cr k}` or `\rlap{\kern.18em\raise.7ex\hbox{\tiny f}}k`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - you may be right. :-)

Comment: editer version is not good. Hyphenation not working, ugly described. I need normal k. this is meaning normal k not \kf or other not normal k. I need write word 'kot' 'kociołek' etc.   NOT '\kfociłek' '\kfot'

Comment: @Pankracy - I have no good idea what the new glyphs you're looking to create are really supposed to look like or in which contexts they may be used. The best advice I can give at this point was already brought up by morbusg in a comment: start using a real font-editing program such as `fontforge`. Do you want me to delete this answer? Please advise.

Comment: fontforge is to complicated. I need only one new letter 'k'.